# C++ count time overcoming 72 minutes range of clock_t

Tags: c++, count, portability, execution-time

I'm trying to count the execution time of part of my application, but since I need to get milliseconds, and I need to get long execution times too. I'm currently using clock_t = clock() from ctime, but it has a range of only 72 minutes I think, which is not suitable for my needs. Is there any other **portable** way to count large execution times keeping millisecond precision? Or some way so overcome this limitation of clock_t ?

Comment: You aren't getting millisecond precision anyway -- at least on Windows, the clock is only accurate to 10-15 ms.

Comment: Where did you get the figure of 72 minutes?  If clock_t is a 32-bit value, that'll be about 71,500 minutes or 49.7 days.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: On many platforms (and all Posix platforms) `clock()` has microsecond precision, so a 32-bit `clock_t` overflows after about 72 minutes.

Comment: ah my bad; the OP mentioned ms so I assumed...  I always do this stuff in one place and forget about it, passing deltaTime (usually as floating point seconds) around instead.

Answer (score 3):

The first question you need to ask is do you ***really*** need millisecond precision in time spans over a hour.

If you do one simple method (without looking around for libraries that do it already)is just track when the timer rolls over and add that to another variable.

Comment: The important takeaway is that the OP should accumulate time deltas in a way that will be valid for the expected runtime of the application.  There's no reason why you can't accumulate the deltas in a 64 bit integer; 64 bits of milliseconds should be enough for anyone.  (It's allows over 584 million years.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are none that I know of that are cross-platform (that's not to say there doesn't exist any, however).

Nevertheless, it is easy enough to work around this problem. Just create a separate thread (ex: boost.thread) which sleeps for a long time, adds the time difference so far to a total, then repeats. When the program is shut down, stop the thread where it can also add to this counter before it quits.